# How to resize UITextField as user types in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, resize, uitextfield

I'm trying to write a messaging application in Swift on IOS8.  Essentially I'm trying to mimic what the texting app in IOS does when you reach the edge of the textfield--the height of the textfield increases, and a new line is made. Right now when I type, the words just scroll to the side. How can I prevent the side scrolling and instead resize the textfield?

Comment: use textview instead of textfield.

Comment: I guess my reason for using a textfield was so that I could have placeholder text and a rounded border...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely use `UITextView` combined with its `textViewDidChange:` delegate method. You can track when the inside text changes and update your textView width (or height) accordingly by measuring its content size from constraints you specify.

You can also reimplement `drawRect:` to add your rounded borders or customize properties of its `layer` (like `cornerRadius`).

Placeholder can be also implemented by tracking text changes (whether by delegate methods or notifications).

I agree this isn't optimal, but at least you still have options to mimic `UITextField` behaviors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a method that can tell me how many lines of text that have been typed in the textview?

Comment: You cannot know the number of lines directly but instead you can ask the textView what's its content size (with `contentSize` property). It gets automatically updated while you type in. The only requirement is that you force its width to be something you specify with a layout constraint or by setting its frame (only if no auto-layout). Otherwise, it won't be able to compute the content size.